# Jquery fadeIn text on accordion menu

Tags: jquery, accordion, fadein, fadeout

Looking for a little help on how to make text fade in on an accordion menu.  More specifically, when clicking on a menu item, I want the text that displays underneath to fade in, and fade out when that menu is closed. I'm new to Jquery and although I understand the basic concept, I can't get it to work with the current code in place.

Example: http://codepen.io/Sektion66/pen/ouclt

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks.

Comment: Instead of linking directly to your example and hoping someone will figure out your code for you, you'll get a better response if you can post the area of code you want assistance with.

Comment: Well I found a solution and attempted to answer my own question, but it didn't seem to post.  I'll find the time to post it again later today.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix my original issue with a combination of CSS and Jquery.

The issue was this...   I had to force visibility while animating the accordion as graphic elements are hanging outside of the content area.  In doing so the main text elements would also display outside of this area during animation.  Resulting in a sloppy look.

The fix...  Using CSS I set the main opacity of the main text area to 0 initially, then when a menu item is clicked it adds a CSS class which will fade in the text, and when clicked off, will fade out.

So in it's most basic form:

**CSS**

```
.initialState {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.fadeIn { 
  opacity: 1; 
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

**JS**

```
.slideDown().addClass("fadeIn");
.slideUp().removeClass("fadeIn");
```

Example: http://codepen.io/Sektion66/pen/ouclt

Thanks for the help everyone.  Hopefully this Accordion menu will come in handy for others,  so go nuts!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$allCells.slide(Up|Down)` to `$allCells.fade(In|Out)`. Now you have other problems because you are using large selectors. Try to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook into the `activate(event, ui)` [event](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate) in the control.

Create a handler like the code sample below and see if you can just fade the entire panel in to start with. This may well give you weird results as I haven't tested this, just suggesting where to start.

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion({
  activate: function( event, ui ) { ui.newPanel.fadeIn(); }
});
```

If it messes with your layout or rendering then you need to get a reference to the text elements inside the `newPanel` object and fade them all explicitly.

Comment: Is he even using the accordion plug in?